# failed to change '' to null for datetime in mysql stored procedure

Tags: mysql, datetime, stored-procedures, ifnull

i wrote the stored procedure:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_create_new_task`(
IN  _taskName       VARCHAR(30),
IN  _description    VARCHAR(500),
IN  _startDate      DATETIME,
IN  _endDate        DATETIME,
IN  _lacation       VARCHAR(30),
IN  _subTo          INT
)
BEGIN

INSERT INTO tm_tasks (taskName, description, startDate, endDate, lacation,      subTo)
VALUES (_taskName, _description, NULLIF(_startDate,''), NULLIF(_endDate,''), _lacation, _subTo);

END
```

I run it:

```
call task_tool.SP_create_new_task('name1 ', 'description1', '', '', 'lacation1', 1);
```

and got this error:

```
Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '' for column '_startDate' at row 1
```

why NULLIF() didn't enter Null value to _startDate???

for your convenience, task table query:

```
CREATE TABLE tm_tasks(
ID              INT         PRIMARY KEY AUTO_INCREMENT,
taskName        VARCHAR(30) NOT NULL,
description     VARCHAR(500),
joinDate        TIMESTAMP,
startDate       DATETIME    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
endDate         DATETIME    NULL DEFAULT NULL,
lacation        VARCHAR(30),
subTo           INT DEFAULT NULL,
ignoreRow       TINYINT(1)  DEFAULT 0
);
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You get this error because it doesn't even get to insert.

> Error Code: 1292. Incorrect datetime value: '' for column '_startDate'
>   at row 1

It fails here:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`root`@`localhost` PROCEDURE `SP_create_new_task`(
IN  _taskName       VARCHAR(30),
IN  _description    VARCHAR(500),
**IN  _startDate      DATETIME**,
```

When you try to pass '' to `DATETIME` parameter.

What you trying to do:

**'' -> _startDate DATETIME parameter** -> INSERT -> NULLIF(_startDate, '') -> NULL

should be:

NULL -> _startDate DATETIME parameter -> INSERT -> NULL

Pass `NULL` directly and don't do workaround with `NULLIF()`.

```
CALL task_tool.SP_create_new_task('name1 ', 'description1', NULL, NULL, 'lacation1', 1);
```